# Calling a DB outside android activity class

Tags: android

I'm writing am expense reporting application for a software enengineering class.  I plan on using parse.com for my database but I'm having trouble creating a DBClass to manage my queries.  I would like this to be a file outside my android activities however I keep getting an error when i put my DB logic out of the activity.

My question is how do I package my database logic into a class that I then instantiate in my activity?

Thank you

Comment: well what is the error

Comment: your database accessing class will likely need access to some Context. You can make it a Service (for example, "extends IntentService") or you can pass the Context as a parameter to the methods of your class that need it. Or you can pass the context in to your class's constructor and hang on to a reference to it. Other than that, what's the problem?

Comment: I ended up creating an android "Application" class for this!  Thanks!